# GridLayout: how to make view fit cell

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm creating a simple login interface using the `GridLayout`.
I would like that the two `EditText` fit the cells where they are.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.
[image]
The green dashed lines show the `GridLayout` borders while the blue lines show the borders of the `EditText` field.
As you can see The `EditText` is longer than the screen limit.

Here is the xml code of the `EditText`

```
           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail_loginFragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
                app:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Even if I change the layout_width attribute, the problem persist. It looks like android ignore that attribute.

How can I fix that, please?

Comment: why don't you use `Table Layout` instead?

Comment: Just because I've never used `TableLayout`. But I would like to know what is wrong with `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You are fixing the EditText width with the ems attribute, that's why changes in the layout_width are having no effect. Try a lower value, or just remove it if you don't want the field to have a fixed size.

Comment: Actually with or without ems attribute, it doesn't change anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found to create the GridView is to use RecyclerView with the GridLayouy manager. Adapter implementations is the same as for normal RecyclerView

You can create GridLayout manager like this

```
//3 is the row span
GridLayoutManager a = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
```

This will help you to improve performance and create your view with the ViewHolder pattern